# I want my calendar component to show enabled only the days of the month that I have selected using react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, calendar, date-fns, react-datepicker

As I said in the title, my component calendar is showing enabled all the days in the date popover my desired behavior is like the date input the days of the past and next month show disabled if I'm not in this month examples below:

This is my Calendar in the image we can see the days of the previous month and the next are enabled.

[image]

This is the expected behavior the previous and next month days are disabled

[image]

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import './calendar.css';
import { getMonth } from 'date-fns';

export const Calendar: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<Date | null>(null);
  const [activeMonth, setActiveMonth] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const handleDateChange = (date: Date | null) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
    setActiveMonth(date ? getMonth(date) : null);
  };

  const highlightSelectedDay = (dayOfMonth: number, date?: Date): React.ReactNode => {
    const isSelected = selectedDate && date && date.getTime() === selectedDate.getTime();
    return (
      <div className={`day-wrapper ${isSelected ? 'selected' : ''}`}>
        {dayOfMonth}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar-container">
      <DatePicker
        className="calendar"
        selected={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        renderDayContents={highlightSelectedDay}
        inline
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```